# Updating an Email Address in the Automation Studio Audience DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have a Data Extension as an Automation Studio Audience for a Journey. Through the Journey the Email Address in the DE may get updated. We have the Journey Settings as "Use Email Address from Entry Source only".

So if our process is like this:

1. Contact enters Journey with email address aaa@somewhere.com
2. Email gets sent to aaa@somewhere.com
3. Automation Studio Audience DE gets email address field updated to bbb@somewhereelse.com
4. Email gets sent to bbb@somewhereelse.com

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

As documentation mentions **journey data**, I guess journey/event data is used which during the whole journey represents the state of the entry source data extension at the time of journey entry. So according to documentation the email should be sent to *aaa@somewhere.com* in your example.

If you already started implementing your journey, validation of this should be pretty easy.

> When journey data from the entry source includes the email address that should be used as default, set that email address as default by choosing Use Email Address From Entry Source Only.
> (Source: [Journey Settings - Default Channel Addresses](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/))

**Documentation articles:**

- [Journey Settings - Default Channel Addresses](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/)
- [Journey and Contact Data](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/using_event_data/)

Comment: We also have that Automation Studio Audience set as the Primary in the Channel Address Order. So is it not possible to have an email address to change during a Journey?

Comment: Retrieval using Channel Address Order / All Subscribers could work. However I couldn't find anything regarding lookup of the email address in that case of using channel address order.